# Не отображается картинка в тэге <img src>

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день. Сделал страничку, на которой отображаю картинку из тэга img src"", но она не отображается до того, как не откроешь браузер с нуля. Вот ее код:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function getCustomer(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "/customer/"+customerLogin,false);
        xhr.send(null);

        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var customerPhoto = data.photo.linkLocation;
        var customer = data.customers[0];
        customerLogin = customer.login;

        document.getElementById("customerLogin").value = customerLogin;
        document.getElementById("customerPassword").value =   
                customer.password;
        document.getElementById("customerName").value = customer.name;
        document.getElementById("customerSurname").value = customer.surname;
        document.getElementById("customerPhone").value = customer.phone;

        var img = document.getElementById("customerPhoto");
        alert(customerPhoto);
        img.setAttribute("src",customerPhoto);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body class="profile" onload="pageReady();getCustomer();">
    <div class="photo">
        <br/><img id="customerPhoto" width="500" height="500"><br/></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Лишнее не добавлял. При загрузке страницы alert выводит правильный путь к картинке, но загружается она только при повторном открытии страницы браузера или многократных перезагрузок страниц. Понимаю в этом пока маловато (учусь), это не с кэшем связано, случайно? Спасибо.

Comment: стоит посмотреть ошибки в консоли когда не загружается

Comment: Поместите скрипт после тега картинки в конец страницы.

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya, как это поможет в данном случае?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya не помогло...

Comment: ошибки в консоли смотрели? функция pageReady определена в коде? можете удалить из представленного кода лишнее - заполнение инпутов, к примеру?

Comment: @Grundy 404 ошибка

Comment: 404 ошибка по какому запросу?

Comment: @ИванПшеницын не могу это страница с данными пользователя их все нужно отобразить...Была отдельная ф-я photoUpload при загрузке страницы - тоже самое pageRady - глобальная - работает на всех страницах и на этой тоже - проблем с ней нет.

Comment: @НиколайЕгоров я имею ввиду удалить лишнее здесь, в вопросе. Заполнение инпутов точно не ломает картинку, но мешает быстро понять код.

Comment: так, похоже разобрался...У меня тут связь с Restcontroller Java через Tomcat....Ошибка, похоже при обращении к ресурсам...

Comment: onload="pageReady();getCustomer();" я бы не стал так делать

Comment: @tCode не делай)) Дай похардкорить людям)

Comment: @tCode почему? я учусь) писал на Java сервер пришлось в Javascript по-немногу вникать)